# How to build exhaust system?

Tags: exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

I light candles frequently in room, and I wanted to prevent candle soot from sticking to the walls etc. How about I install an exhaust system in that room? What other options do I have?

How powerful are kitchen's exhaust systems? Do they suck air only around the stove area or few feet farther as well?

Comment: No, kitchen exhaust systems create a mild vacuum around the stove which remains unfilled until the system is turned off.  If kitchen exhaust systems are built too powerfully, the risk of a fatal vacuum area around the stove is quite real.

Comment: That was a joke. ;)

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo lol, obviously, it is still going to suck air, I want to know if it's effective enough that I can light candle at that distance and not worry about soot.

Comment: It's only effective if the candles are fairly close to the range. Any distance away, the soot will rise and condense on surfaces long before the small horizontal air movement can move the soot to the exhaust. The exhaust needs to be more or less above the candles to be effective.